# Build resource only apk and interact with main App

Tags: android

I have an app, that the main app access and display the resources (like books) provided by the app itself. I could include all resources into the apk. But this is not what I want now. I want the resources be able to installed/uninstalled separately (there might be multiple resources as well).

One option I know is that the app itself can have a downloader to retrieve the files from a server, but I don't prefer to host a server for that.
And I notice there is an APK expansion option in Google Play now, but my app is likely an in-house application that can not public in google play.

What I am thinking now, is that I build an apk just with the resource and minimum installation code. But now the question is how to install the resource files so that they are visible to the app.

I know the resource files from the resource app can be accessed by the main app as long as they are installed in external sdcard and the main app have permission of read/write from it. This is not a problem. But how can the main app gets to know that there is new resource available and add the path to the list?

Can I let the resource app send an Intent to the main app somehow, providing the new path of the resource?

Comment: Why not just have a file on your server which lists all available resource files  and you compare with what is on device?

Comment: @MorrisonChang You said "on your server", does it mean on the app? If yes, then you mean the app knows what resource it could have, and it scans the directories to find out what resources available from other apps?

Comment: I just figured out that the resources will not be extracted when the apk is installed, and they stay in the apk file and the program can extract the resource when they need. So this creates some problem if one apk wants to access the resource files from another apk. Perhaps I have to programmically extract all resource file to somewhere.